# Can excel calculate permutations of numbers given a condition?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Disclaimer: *I know how to program this in a programming language and I bet I could sweat through VBA as well :) but I am explicitly looking for a way on how Excel or add-in operations like the "Solver" could solve this issue:*

Let's say I have 20 rows with one cell each, in each cell there is one value in the range [1..20] (might be random, might be continuous, does not really matter)

Additionally I have another cell, whose value is fixed, e.g `19`.

Can excel generate all possible permutations of those cells that would result in a `Sum` operation of being 19?

Here is a stupid example of one permutation for *Sum of 19*, but images always help :)

[image: permutation]

This is only one of various permutations of course and I do not require to highlight cells as this gets crowded quickly. 
Some Add-Ins  like "Solver" can generate new sheets as report which then can be used to perform further analysis.

I recently learnt that excel is able to simulate mathematical and physical models and I wonder whether it also can do this.

Comment: This is called the Knapsack Problem.  And no, Excel cannot do this natively.  It will take programming.  You can google `Knapsack Problem Excel` maybe there is an add on.  But most likely you will need to program it yourself.

Comment: @ScottCraner I guessed so, but AFAIK Knapsack optimizes on certain parameters like value, weight etc where I am rather looking at all possible solutions as they are all of equal value in my problem.